# MongoDB data not persisting between taking docker containers down and up again [MacOSX]

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

When I take docker containers down and up again, my MongoDB collections are all gone.

- I run `docker-compose up` and add a new database, collection, and document.
- I then run `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up`.
- Data is gone.

It works fine if I am just stopping and starting the containers though. My host machine is macOS Mojave 10.14 with Docker Desktop 2.1.

I have the following docker-compose.yaml version 3.4 file:

```
  mongodb:
      image: mongo:4.2.1
      volumes:
           - ./docker/data/mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb:rw
      ports:
      - target: 27017
        published: 27018
        protocol: tcp
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the volume mounts. When I look on my host machine at ./docker/data/mongodb nothing is being written to it, ever. I went ahead and set permissions to 777 on that to see if it was a permissions issue, hail mary, I know.

Comment: Try to remove `:rw` and `build`

Comment: You mean remove `:rw` and then do a `docker-compose build`? Not sure what else you mean by "build" as its not in the sample I posted.

Comment: Everytime you change Docker-compose file, you need to build to apply changes. Try my suggested answer before removing `:rw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes

```
volumes:
       - "./docker/data/mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb"
```

**Note:** MongoDB by default points `/data/db`

Answer (score 0):

From the docs here:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

You will need to mount the custom volume into `/data/db`, not `/var/lib/mongodb`